# Select certain rows in a table in InDesign CC

Tags: adobe-indesign, creative-cloud, formatting, tables

Is there a way to multi select different rows in a table in indesign without having them all selected? E.g. made an example table and say I want to just edit row 1 and 3, but it highlights row 2 as well.

Used Shift click to select the rows.

[image]

Comment: This seems a bit like an X/Y problem.. *why* would you need to select non-continuous rows? (I don't think you can, by the way) Why aren't cell or table styles enough? -- e.g. zebra striping can be done automatically via table options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to click and select specific rows/columns. It will just select the entire range between your clicks.

With *Table Options* you can apply formatting using a defined *Alternating Pattern*, like odd rows, even rows, etc ... but that's all you can do with this.

[image]